# Aldryn cloud on windows 10, using hyper-v, and docker 1.12 rc2 beta16

Tags: docker, npm, windows-10, hyper-v, divio

Has anyone any clues for setting up aldryn cloud solution on windows 10, using latest docker beta and hyper-v?

When running 
`docker-compose -f C:\Users\Me\project\docker-compose-windows.yml build` 
I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse-fb/-/estraverse-fb-1.3.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.clonedeep/-/lodash.clonedeep-3.0.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/user-home/-/user-home-2.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-7.0.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze/-/gaze-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash.clonedeep/-/lodash.clonedeep-3.0.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/user-home/-/user-home-2.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-7.0.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze/-/gaze-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.13-moby
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v0.12.14
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c (cd / && npm-install-retry -- --production)' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm not even sure this is the culprit, but I stumbled upon: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9863

The solution provided there gives me:

```
sed: can't read ./lib/utils/rename.js: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd $(npm root -g)/npm && npm install fs-extra && sed -i -e s/graceful-fs/fs-extra/ -e s/fs.rename/fs.move/ ./lib/utils/rename.js' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Am I on the right way? Has anyone succeeded yet and are you willing/able to share?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your docker VM can't talk to the outside world, or at least it can't talk to its DNS server:

```
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
```

Please make sure the following command work (in that order) before proceeding:

```
docker run --rm -it busybox ping 8.8.8.8  # Tests raw TCP traffic
docker run --rm -it busybox ping google.com  # Tests DNS connectivity
```

Aldryn also includes a nice utility to check for all this on your behalf:

```
aldryn doctor
```

In most cases, when encountering networking issues, restarting the docker VM helps:

```
docker-machine restart default
```

But in the case of Hyper-V it might be because of a missing network configuration as well.

Comment: Right now I had to undo the Hyper-V setup and go back to VirtualBox.  It will take some effort to go back and be out of business for my live site.       
  
I was able to do "project setup", and as I remember "aldryn doctor" was fine. I concluded network config was OK. I did many restarts, even deleted machine and recreated it.    

Could it be a network config problem when"project setup" was OK?

Comment: I encounter these issues a lot when switching networks (e.g. from wifi to wired). Could that be the case?

Comment: I'm always wired behind my dekstop. Aldryn did some machine updates lately. When I'm in a position not needing live for a while, I might check further. You don't recognize the specific error?

Comment: I just did some updates on Aldryn and tried to deploy again. It seems like there are similar problems. See http://pastebin.com/sdequKnH

Comment: The deployment issues are mostly due to npm registry not living up to expectations. You get an NPM error locally simply because it is the first thing accessing the network (and it fails on the DNS resolution already).